# how to count the number of items in cart

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am developing an online shopping site..so when the user adds any item to the cart i store it in a table...now what i want is to count the number of items in the cart as well as update the number of items in cart every time the user adds a new item....

Please help me...i am very new to asp.net.

```
Public Function AddToCart(ByVal itemID As String, ByVal itemName As String, ByVal itemPrice As Integer, _
                          ByVal offer As String, ByVal buyNo As String, ByVal userID As String) As String

        Dim sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO shoppingCart" & _
            "(buyNo, userID, itemID, itemName, itemPrice, offer, itemQtty)" & _
            "VALUES('" & buyNo & "','" & userID & "','" & itemID & "','" & itemName & "'," & itemPrice & ",'" & offer & "'," & _
                    "1)"

        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databaseConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr)
        'Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        '                                       "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;" & _
        '                                       "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con)
        con.Open()
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Item with 'Item ID: " & itemID & "' & 'Item Name: " & itemName & _
               "' has been added to the cart!")

        Dim sno As Integer = CType(Replace(buyNo, userID, ""), Integer)
        sno = sno + 1
        buyNo = userID & sno

        Return buyNo
    End Function
```

Comment: If you're very new you better use something out of the box that comes with full documentation.

Comment: do you mind helping me out???

Comment: @Gens i am storing the information of the  products in the database table..so how do i count the number of items in the database??

Comment: This code will be open to sql injection attacks. Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're very new in programming, but everybody starts at some point.

**IF** you're using any sort of databse to back you up on the back end, you could do something like this:

```
select sum(item_quantity) from user_shopping_cart
```

to give you the number of items in the user shopping cart.